# PHP: Faster to check if variable is integer or starts with #

Tags: php, string, integer

I'm developing a module with some arrays in it.
Now my array contains:

```
$omearray = array (
  '#title' = 'title',
  0 = array ( 'another array', '2ndvalue', ),
  );

foreach($omearray as $key => $value)
```

When I load the array to display I want to check whether the `$key` value is a `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. or a `$key` value that starts with a `#`.

Which would be better to use: checking if the value `is_int()` or a regex that checks whether the first character is a `#`?

**EDIT:** checking stringpos 1 is `#` vs `is_int()` since regex seems to be slow.

Comment: A regex is really slow compared to other string-manipulating functions. If you want to check if the first character is a `#`, use `strpos($key, '#') === 0` (and be sure to use three `=` as I did, reason explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `if ($key[0]=='#')` is faster and `is_int()` is exhaustive, and `||` is a short circuit operator with left associativity (evaluates from left to right, see example 1 on http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) I would say:

```
if ($key[0]=='#' || is_int($val)) /* etc */
```

Because this way you only need to bother about using the # key naming self made convention with the keys you'll compare so much that you'd benefit from an optimization.

But unless you're making a huge number of evaluations I would stick to just `if(is_int($val))`, because it's clearer and less messy.

Answer (score 2):

I would check it using `if($key[0]=="#")`

You can also check if the $value is an array (`is_array($value)`), in this case you dont need either regex,is_int, and # char.

PS: `#` character means (somewhere) "I'm a number/ID"

Comment: And why do you use this approach above the is_int method? I would say checking for integer is much more flexible because you are not depending on the # character.

Comment: @Baszz If there are '#' characters before numbers and there are not # before others than this is the fastest way to check if its a number.
BUT the # character can be redundant, because there is a function to do this - is_int()

Comment: If you are sure that the # is always there, you are absolutely right. I was just wondering what drove your to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the `is_int()`, because you are not dependent on the string. It can be anything and your code will still just take the integer indeices. Looking for # as the first character will prevent that flexibility. But if you are absolutely sure that the string's first character will always be a #, than the `$Key[0] == '#'` will be the fastest option.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (is_int($val) || $val{0} == '#') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much insight into your actual data or reason for choosing this structure, but depending on that info, altering your structure so that you aren't inter-mixing integer indexes with hash keys may be an option:

```
$omearray = array(
    '#title' => 'title',
    'foo' => array(
        'anotherarray',
        '2ndvalue'
    )
);

foreach ($omearray as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'foo') {
        // do something with $value, which is the 2nd array, numerically indexed
    }
}
```

Apologies if this solution doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Nope doesn't work for me data is generated in the way i provided above. also I'm not asking on the how but more the which is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if string is integer
or if it starts with #
or both
or whatever.

It's all makes not a slightest difference.

It is not a part of your code that may affect any performance issue ever.